# Destructor is called on unwanted object during assignment

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, destructor

```
myClassVar = MyClass(3);
```

I expected destructor being called on the previously created `myClassVar` on the left.
But it is actually being called on the new object that's created by `MyClass(3)`.

My full test code and output follows..

### edit

How do I fix the problem?
Implement an assignment operator?
MyClass actually has pointers, and MYSQL_STMT*, I wonder how should I deal with MYSQL_STMT* variable.

I just need MyClassVar(3) object not the MyClassVar() which was first created when ClientClass object was created.

I came across this situation fairly often, and wonder if there's a good way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { printf("MyClass %p\n", this); }
    MyClass(int a) { printf("Myclass(int) %p\n", this); }
    ~MyClass() { printf("~MyClass %p\n", this); }

private:
    int mA;
};


class ClientClass
{
public:
    void Foo()
    {
        printf("before &myClassVar : %p\n", &myClassVar);
        myClassVar = MyClass(3); // this is the important line
        printf("after &myClassVar : %p\n", &myClassVar);
    }

private:
    MyClass myClassVar;
};

int main()
{   
    ClientClass c;
    c.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
MyClass 0x7fff5fbfeba0
before &myClassVar : 0x7fff5fbfeba0
Myclass(int) 0x7fff5fbfeb70
~MyClass 0x7fff5fbfeb70 // <--- here destructor is called on the newly created object
after &myClassVar : 0x7fff5fbfeba0
~MyClass 0x7fff5fbfeba0
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how the critical line breaks down:

```
myClassVar = MyClass(3);
```

First, `MyClass(3)` calls constructor and returns the object.

Second, `myClassVar =` copies the object to `myClassVar`.

Then the statement ends. The object (which is an immediate) is dead, and thus the destructor is invoked.

**EDIT :**

As for how to get around this. The only way I can think of is to use a [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new). I'm not sure if there's a better solution other than making a "set" method.

Comment: By "set" method, you mean copy constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: More like a separate method that combines the two in an efficient way. Basically, it destroys the existing object and creates a new one in it's place. (this would have to be defined within the class)

Answer (score 2):

```
myClassVar = MyClass(3);
```

`myClassVar` continues to exist after this line. The lifetime of `MyClass(3)` ends at the semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

As the other posts mentioned the object with the custom constructor `MyClass(3)` gets destroyed after the assignment operation `myClassVar = MyClass(3)`. In this case you do not need a custom assignment operator because the compiler generated one copies the member **mA** to the already existing object myClassVar.

However since MyClass defines its own destructor you should adhere to the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), which mandates that in such a case you should implement a custom assignment operator as well.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to your edit: how do you fix what problem?  It's not clear
what the problem is.  If your class needs a destructor (and there's no
polymorphism in play), it probably needs both an assignment operator and
a copy constructor.  Similarly, when "tracking" construcctions and
destructions, you should probably provide both as well, since they will
be called.

Otherwise: if the problem is that you're constructing and then
assigning, rather than constructing with the correct value immediately,
the simple answer is "don't do it".  The compiler does what you tell it 
to.  If you write:

```
MyClass var;
var = MyClass(3);
```

you have default construction, followed by the construction of a
temporary, assignment, and the destruction of the temporary.  If you
write:

```
MyClass var(3);
```

or

```
MyClass var = 3;
```

you only have one construction.  (Note that despite appearances, there
is **no** assignment in the last snippet.  Only construction.)

For class members, this difference appears in the way you write the
constructor:

```
ClientClass::ClientClass() { var = MyClass(3); }
```

is default construction, followed by creation, assignment and
destruction of a temporary;

```
ClientClass::ClientClass() : var( 3 ) {}
```

is just construction with the correct value.  (Rather obviously, this
second form is preferred.)